# How to get the id attribute when I'm inside the perform_validation method of the serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

When I'm inside the perform_validation method of a given serializer I need access to the "id" of the model I've requested (at my RetrieveUpdateDestroy endpoint)

```
def perform_validation(self, attrs):
    name = attrs['name']
    guid = attrs['id'] #broken :(
```

What is the best way to get this when I'm inside the validation method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the serializer context, that's provided by the generic view.

See here for what context is populated by default: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L83

You should be able to do something like this: `self.context['view'].kwargs['pk']`